# Unwrapping models so they use the maximum space

Tags: uv

I don't quite know how to ask this in Google so I ask here instead. I'm getting better in baking my models but there's an issue that has come couple of times now. When I have small strips for instance around the roof or the base of the house (they might be called baseboards in English), the bake unwrap unwraps them as big empty squares (or well the form of the mesh it's surrounding). In any case, the you get a huge empty space inside the UV map with no textures and it seems like a really inefficient use of texture space. Here's a picture to understand it better:

[image]

Is there a way to play around this? Either on the model or in the uwunwrap?

Comment: It is inefficient.  You should look at UV packing addons; several exist, some for free.

Comment: Are you using any yourself? Any free ones you could recommend?